# geode client server version not supported - Peer or client version with ordinal 100 not supported

Tags: java, gemfire, geode, spring-data-gemfire, spring-boot-data-geode

I've a springboot app hosted on PCF trying to connect to PCC(pivotal cloud cache). I've spinned up a PCC instance and binded it to my app and pushed the app to cloud foundry. I've added all the required gemfire starter dependencies to springboot and it appears like it was able to read the locator and server information from VCAP_SERVICES. But, I see the following error on spring boot app startup.

```
org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.ConnectionFactoryImpl.createClientToServerConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:120) - Could not create a new connection to server: XXX.XXX.XX.XXX(cacheserver-c3a291d1-9664-40d5-b20c-ad8dca8cd19e:1)<v3>:56152(version:GEODE 1.7.0) refused connection: 
Peer or client version with ordinal 100 not supported. Highest known version is 1.7.0 Client: /XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:39192.

at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.Handshake.readMessage(Handshake.java:330) ~[geode-core-1.9.2.jar!/:?]
```

I'm not sure what ordinals means here and also what dependencies need to be updated.

Here are my maven dependencies..

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-gemfire</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.geode</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-geode</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pivotal.gemfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>geode-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-geode</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.geode</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-geode-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is my config file..

```
@Configuration
@ClientCacheApplication(name = "Test", logLevel = "info")
@EnableCachingDefinedRegions(
    clientRegionShortcut = ClientRegionShortcut.PROXY,
    serverRegionShortcut = RegionShortcut.REPLICATE_HEAP_LRU)
@EnableClusterAware
@EnablePdx
public class CloudConfiguration {}
```

Any help?

Comment: Spring seems to be using Apache geode, so since your error seems to be an incompatibility issue maybe try to change pivotal version of geode-core to [apache one](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.geode/geode-core/1.12.0)?

Comment: Hi Jorge, I cannot update enterprise hosted pivotal dependencies. Trying to find the root cause on the client Spring Boot App and see if it can be resolved. It could be geode/gemfire dependency version. Not sure at this point.

Comment: Fair enough... So your error may also means that your version is too updated for whatever server since it says to only know highest version to be 1.7.0... maybe downgrading your dependency for pivotal one?

Comment: Agreed with the other answers, this is probably a compatibility issue between your servers and clients. I'd suggest to double check the version of PCC in use (along with the GemFire version shipped with PCC), and **make sure** the GemFire version on the client application is not higher.

Answer (score 2):

Though you solved your issue yourself and sort of got to the gist of the problem, I wanted to provide a bit more detail here (for interested readers), as well as provide some guidance.

Let's start from the beginning:

First, your application dependencies, as shown in the Maven POM above, are very confused!

You are declaring direct, "versioned" dependencies on *Spring Data GemFire* (i.e. `org.springframework.data:spring-data-gemfire:2.2.1.RELEASE`) along with *Spring Data Geode* (i.e. `org.springframework.data:spring-data-geode:2.2.6.RELEASE`, which do not match; SD GemFire 2.2.1 != SD Geode 2.2.6) along with *Spring Boot for Apache Geode & Pivotal GemFire* (SBDG) (`org.springframework.geode:spring-geode-starter:1.2.6.RELEASE`), and then unnecessarily pull in SBDG's `spring-geode` (core) module, which would be transitively pulled in by the `spring-geode-starter` anyway, as well as declaring the `org.apache.geode:geode-core` module, phew! :)

The only dependency you need to declare in this case is 1 of SBDG's starters, either `org.springframework.geode:spring-geode-starter` when using Apache Geode or `org.springframework.geode:spring-gemfire-starter` when using Pivotal GemFire, or alternatively when deploying your *Spring Boot* application to PCF using PCC (in which case, the `spring-gemfire-starter` dependency is recommended, though not absolutely necessary since it is possible to mix GemFire/Geode peers and have Geode clients talk to GemFire serves or vice versa).

The starter pulls in *Spring Data Geode* (or *Spring Data GemFire*, depending on the *starter*) which pulls in the Geode (or GemFire) bits for you.  That is the point of Maven/Gradle dependency management in the first place and it is better to minimize your application dependency declarations as much as possible and just let the framework/starter decide the versions of the transitive dependencies for you, especially if you don't care.

The *Spring Boot* project in general goes to great lengths to [curate and harmonize all the dependency versions](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.2.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L34-L244) (both *Spring* and 3rd party libs/transitive dependencies included) for you.  You only need to choose the version of the *Spring Boot* based on the versions of the application dependencies (e.g. Apache Geode or Pivotal GemFire) that you require.

We try to summarize those for you here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/wiki/Spring-Boot-for-Apache-Geode-and-Pivotal-GemFire-Version-Compatibility-Matrix

Specifically, see:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/wiki/Spring-Boot-for-Apache-Geode-and-Pivotal-GemFire-Version-Compatibility-Matrix#version-compatibility-matrix

To be very transparent, this version compatibility matrix/table, roughly translates into:

1. As a developer, I am using or choosing to use SBDG `1.2.6.RELEASE`.
2. SBDG `1.2.6.RELEASE` is [based on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.2.6.RELEASE/gradle.properties#L9) *Spring Boot* `2.2.6.RELEASE`.
3. *Spring Boot* `2.2.6.RELEASE` [pulls in](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.2.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L192) *Spring Data* `Moore-SR6`.
4. *Spring Data* `Moore-SR6` ([this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-build/blob/2.2.6.RELEASE/bom/pom.xml#L5-L7)) [includes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-build/blob/2.2.6.RELEASE/bom/pom.xml#L51-L63) *Spring Data GemFire/Geode* `2.2.6.RELEASE`.
5. *Spring Data Geode* (SDG) `Moore-SR6/2.2.6.RELEASE` is [based on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/2.2.6.RELEASE/pom.xml#L25) *Apache Geode* `1.9.x`.
6. *Spring Data GemFire* (SDG) `Moore-SR6/2.2.6.RELEASE` is [based on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.2.6.RELEASE/pom.xml#L25) *Pivotal GemFire* `9.8.x`.
7. *Spring Data Geode* [includes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/2.2.6.RELEASE/pom.xml#L117-L167) the required (by SDG) and correct Apache Geode bits (dependencies).
8. *Spring Data GemFire* [includes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.2.6.RELEASE/pom.xml#L117-L154) the required (by SDG) and correct Pivotal GemFire bits (dependencies).

Therefore it becomes a matter of what version of SBDG (i.e. which `spring-[geode|gemfire]-starter` version) do you need to use with PCC in PCF?

For that, you must have a general understanding that GemFire/Geode clients can only connect to and communicate with GemFire/Geode servers at the same version as the client or later. A newer client CANNOT talk to an older GemFire/Geode server.  This is not a Spring restriction, but a GemFire/Geode restriction itself.  There are many factors to why this is the case and I won't explain that here (but it roughly boils down to protocols, distributed algorithms and the rest).

By way of example, you can connect a GemFire 9.8 client to a GemFire 9.8.x server and all will be fine.  That same GemFire 9.8 client can also connect to and talk with GeFire 9.9.x and 9.10.x servers.  However, a GemFire 9.8 client cannot connect to or talk with a GemFire 9.7, 9.6, 9.5 or earlier server.  Patch, or maintenance versions do not matter AFAIR, meaning a GemFire 9.8.7 client should be able to connect and talk to a GemFire 9.8.4 server, for example, so long as the `major.minor` versions match.

So now, it essentially boils down to, which version of Pivotal GemFire is the version of PCC in PCF that you are deploying your *Spring Boot* (*Data Geode*) application to, based on?

For that you need to look in the PCF/PCC documentation.

For example, PCC for PCF (now known as VMware Tanzue GemFire for VMs) version 1.11 is based on Pivotal GemFire 9.9.1.  See [here](https://docs.pivotal.io/p-cloud-cache/1-11/product-snapshot.html).

This means you could use SBDG `1.2.6.RELEASE`, which is based on *Spring Boot* `2.2.6.RELEASE`, which pulls in *Spring Data* `Moore-SR6`, which includes SDG `2.2.6.RELEASE`, which is based on Apache Geode `1.9.2`/Pivotal GemFire `9.8.7`.  This combination is fine because the older client (i.e. GemFire `9.8.7`) can connect to and talk with GemFire `9.9.1`, which is the baseline for PCC/VMware Tanzu GemFire for VMS `1.11`.

Make sense?

If we look at PCC 1.10, again that is [based on](https://docs.pivotal.io/p-cloud-cache/1-10/product-snapshot.html) Pivotal GemFire 9.9.1.

If we look at PCC 1.9, it is [based on](https://docs.pivotal.io/p-cloud-cache/1-9/product-snapshot.html) Pivotal GemFire 9.8.6. Again, we are ok here.

If we go back to PCC 1.7, we see that PCC 1.7 was [based on](https://docs.pivotal.io/p-cloud-cache/1-7/product-snapshot.html) Pivotal GemFire 9.7.2.

Now, SBDG `1.2.6.RELEASE` will NOT work with PCC 1.7 since SBDG `1.2.6.RELEASE` is based on GemFire 9.8 (newer) and PCC 1.7 is based on GemFire 9.7 (older).  A 9.8 client cannot connect to and talk with a 9.7 server, therefore, we must go back a SBDG `major.minor` version to SBDG `1.1.x`, where SBDG `1.1.x` is based on *Spring Boot* `2.1`, which pulls in *Spring Data* `Lovelace/2.1`, which includes SDG `2.1.x`, which is based on Apache Geode `1.6` and Pivotal GemFire `9.5`, respectively.

NOTE: While SDG is "compatible" with newer, none "baseline" versions of GemFire/Geode, we do not "support" the combination.  For example, SDG Lovelace/2.1 is "based on" GemFire 9.5/Geode 1.6 only, but is "compatible with" GemFire 9.6/9.7 and Geode 1.7/1.8. If you move beyond GemFire 9.7 to, e.g. 9.8 and Geode 1.8 to 1.9, then of course, you should move to SDG Moore/2.2, since it is "based on" GemFire 9.8/Geode 1.9.  Compatibility != Support.
Anyway, this is to say, you can upgrade your client driver version (i.e. GemFire/Geode client version, if necessary).  See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/wiki/Spring-Data-for-Apache-Geode-&--Pivotal-GemFire-Version-Compatibility-and-Support-Matrix) for more details.  This Wiki page is a WIP.

The [Cloud Cache Developer](https://docs.pivotal.io/cloud-cache-dev/spring-boot/what-youll-need#install-vmware-gemfire) Website also contains details to help get you started.

Finally, I also built this ***Getting Started Sample*** (with [Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.2.x/reference/html5/guides/getting-started.html) and [Source Code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/tree/1.2.6.RELEASE/spring-geode-samples/intro/getting-started)) in the SBDG project itself, that gets you up and running quickly by starting at [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io).

Now, regarding your configuration...

```java
@Configuration
@ClientCacheApplication(name = "Test", logLevel = "info")
@EnableCachingDefinedRegions(
    clientRegionShortcut = ClientRegionShortcut.PROXY,
    serverRegionShortcut = RegionShortcut.REPLICATE_HEAP_LRU)
@EnableClusterAware
@EnablePdx
public class CloudConfiguration {}
```

This can be simplified to:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableCachingDefinedRegions(
  serverRegionShortcut = RegionShortcut.REPLICATE_HEAP_LRU
)
@EnableClusterAware
public class CloudConfiguration {}
```

SBDG "*auto-configures*" a `ClientCache` instance for you, by default.  See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.2.x/reference/html5/#geode-clientcache-applications).

In fact, you should be careful when declaring annotations, explicitly, since then you are overriding the *auto-configuration* (i.e. you are overriding the "*convention*" by applying explicit "*configuration*", which tells *Boot* that you know what you are doing; Make sure that is actually the case!) See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.2.x/reference/html5/#geode-configuration-auto) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.2.x/reference/html5/#geode-configuration-auto-customizing) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.2.x/reference/html5/#geode-configuration-auto-disabling) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.2.x/reference/html5/#geode-configuration-auto-overriding) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.2.x/reference/html5/#geode-configuration-declarative).

Many of the annotation attributes (e.g. `ClientCacheApplication.name` or `ClientCacheApplication.logLevel`) can be expressed as SDG properties in a *Spring Boot* `applications.properties` file, making the configuration more "configurable".

For example:

```
# Spring Boot application.properties.
spring.data.gemfire.name=Test
spring.data.gmefire.cache.log-level=INFO
```

See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.2.x/reference/html5/#geode-configuration-externalized) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.2.x/reference/html5/#geode-configuration-metadata) for more details.

You also do not need to enable PDX explicitly since again SBDG *auto-configures* PDX for you.  See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.2.x/reference/html5/#geode-data-serialization).

The default `ClientRegionShortcut` is PROXY, though I don't mind being "explicit" about it either. You simply just have to be careful in a *Spring Boot* context with *auto-configuration* since you might "override" the *auto-config* and put the responsibility of managing the configuration correctly on yourself. So declare configuration with intent, not blindly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Let's also keep 1 other thing in mind here... this dependency graph/management problem is not exclusive to Spring.  It is nearly the same for all Java applications that you would push to a production environment.  If your application uses Hibernate, or Jackson, or anything else that simplifies your application functionality, you will find similar transitive dependency graphs.  This is a Java problem and why Maven/Gradle, along with other dependency management tools (e.g. Ivy) exist in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: I downgraded the SpringBoot client version to v1.7 and it worked fine. Although, I see authentication issue now.