# Geode/GemFire Cannot create gemfireCache bean error: Spring Boot v2.1.3 - GemFire starter 1.1.0.RELEASE

Tags: cloud-foundry, gemfire, geode, spring-data-gemfire, spring-boot-data-geode

I'm currently using `Springboot v.2.1.3` to connect to `PCC w/ gemfire v9.6.1`. Based on the SBDG compatibility matrix, I tried to use SBDG v1.1.0.RELEASE and I see the below issue.

````
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quoteService' defined in file [C:\Users\madhu\Downloads\pcctest\pcctest\target\classes\com\example\pcctest\QuoteService.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.geode.cache.Region]: Failed to create Region for cache [Quotes]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gemfireCache' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/ClientCacheConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.pcctest.PcctestApplication.main(PcctestApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.geode.cache.Region]: Failed to create Region for cache [Quotes]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gemfireCache' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/ClientCacheConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.annotation.CachingDefinedRegionsConfiguration.lambda$registerRegionBeans$3(CachingDefinedRegionsConfiguration.java:322) ~[spring-data-gemfire-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.annotation.CachingDefinedRegionsConfiguration.registerRegionBeans(CachingDefinedRegionsConfiguration.java:295) ~[spring-data-gemfire-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.annotation.CachingDefinedRegionsConfiguration.access$100(CachingDefinedRegionsConfiguration.java:107) ~[spring-data-gemfire-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.annotation.CachingDefinedRegionsConfiguration$1.postProcessBeforeInitialization(CachingDefinedRegionsConfiguration.java:285) ~[spring-data-gemfire-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:414) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1754) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gemfireCache' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/ClientCacheConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:224) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1115) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:407) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:341) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.annotation.CachingDefinedRegionsConfiguration.lambda$registerRegionBeans$3(CachingDefinedRegionsConfiguration.java:302) ~[spring-data-gemfire-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.ClientCacheFactoryBean.lambda$null$0(ClientCacheFactoryBean.java:118) ~[spring-data-gemfire-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.ClientCacheFactoryBean.lambda$new$1(ClientCacheFactoryBean.java:117) ~[spring-data-gemfire-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.ClientCacheFactoryBean.lambda$applyClientCacheConfigurers$2(ClientCacheFactoryBean.java:156) ~[spring-data-gemfire-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.ClientCacheFactoryBean.applyClientCacheConfigurers(ClientCacheFactoryBean.java:156) ~[spring-data-gemfire-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.ClientCacheFactoryBean.applyClientCacheConfigurers(ClientCacheFactoryBean.java:142) ~[spring-data-gemfire-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.ClientCacheFactoryBean.applyCacheConfigurers(ClientCacheFactoryBean.java:129) ~[spring-data-gemfire-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.CacheFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CacheFactoryBean.java:177) ~[spring-data-gemfire-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted```
````

Here's my pom and config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>pcctest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>pcctest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.geode</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-gemfire-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

````
@Configuration
@EnableCachingDefinedRegions
@EnableClusterConfiguration
public class TestConfig {
}```
````

````
@SpringBootApplication
public class PcctestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PcctestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(QuoteService quoteService) {

        return args -> {
            Quote quote = requestQuote(quoteService, null);
            requestQuote(quoteService, quote.getId());
            requestQuote(quoteService, 10L);
        };
    }

    private Quote requestQuote(QuoteService quoteService, Long id) {

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Quote quote = Optional.ofNullable(id).map(quoteService::requestQuote)
                .orElseGet(quoteService::requestRandomQuote);

        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.printf("\"%1$s\"%nCache Miss [%2$s] - Elapsed Time [%3$s ms]%n", quote, quoteService.isCacheMiss(),
                (elapsedTime - startTime));

        return quote;
    }
}```
````

````
jars that get downloded

org\springframework\geode\spring-gemfire-starter\1.1.0.RELEASE\spring-gemfire-starter-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar
org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.1.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar
org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.1.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar
org\springframework\spring-context\5.1.5.RELEASE\spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar
org\springframework\spring-aop\5.1.5.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar
org\springframework\spring-expression\5.1.5.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar
org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.1.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar
org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.1.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar
ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar
ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar
org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.25\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar
org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.23\snakeyaml-1.23.jar
org\springframework\data\spring-data-gemfire\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-data-gemfire-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar
org\springframework\spring-context-support\5.1.5.RELEASE\spring-context-support-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar
org\springframework\spring-beans\5.1.5.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar
org\springframework\spring-tx\5.1.5.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar
org\springframework\spring-web\5.1.5.RELEASE\spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar
org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar
io\pivotal\gemfire\geode-core\9.5.2\geode-core-9.5.2.jar
com\github\stephenc\findbugs\findbugs-annotations\1.3.9-1\findbugs-annotations-1.3.9-1.jar
org\jgroups\jgroups\3.6.14.Final\jgroups-3.6.14.Final.jar
commons-validator\commons-validator\1.6\commons-validator-1.6.jar
commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.9.2\commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar
commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar
commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.2\commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
commons-digester\commons-digester\2.1\commons-digester-2.1.jar
commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar
it\unimi\dsi\fastutil\8.1.1\fastutil-8.1.1.jar
javax\resource\javax.resource-api\1.7\javax.resource-api-1.7.jar
javax\transaction\javax.transaction-api\1.3\javax.transaction-api-1.3.jar
net\java\dev\jna\jna\4.5.2\jna-4.5.2.jar
net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.4\jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar
org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.11.2\log4j-api-2.11.2.jar
org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.11.2\log4j-core-2.11.2.jar
org\apache\shiro\shiro-core\1.4.0\shiro-core-1.4.0.jar
org\apache\shiro\shiro-lang\1.4.0\shiro-lang-1.4.0.jar
org\apache\shiro\shiro-cache\1.4.0\shiro-cache-1.4.0.jar
org\apache\shiro\shiro-crypto-hash\1.4.0\shiro-crypto-hash-1.4.0.jar
org\apache\shiro\shiro-crypto-core\1.4.0\shiro-crypto-core-1.4.0.jar
org\apache\shiro\shiro-crypto-cipher\1.4.0\shiro-crypto-cipher-1.4.0.jar
org\apache\shiro\shiro-config-core\1.4.0\shiro-config-core-1.4.0.jar
org\apache\shiro\shiro-config-ogdl\1.4.0\shiro-config-ogdl-1.4.0.jar
org\apache\shiro\shiro-event\1.4.0\shiro-event-1.4.0.jar
io\github\lukehutch\fast-classpath-scanner\2.18.1\fast-classpath-scanner-2.18.1.jar
com\healthmarketscience\rmiio\rmiio\2.1.2\rmiio-2.1.2.jar
io\pivotal\gemfire\geode-common\9.5.2\geode-common-9.5.2.jar
io\pivotal\gemfire\geode-json\9.5.2\geode-json-9.5.2.jar
io\pivotal\gemfire\geode-cq\9.5.2\geode-cq-9.5.2.jar
io\pivotal\gemfire\geode-lucene\9.5.2\geode-lucene-9.5.2.jar
org\apache\lucene\lucene-analyzers-common\6.6.2\lucene-analyzers-common-6.6.2.jar
org\apache\lucene\lucene-core\6.6.2\lucene-core-6.6.2.jar
org\apache\lucene\lucene-queries\6.6.2\lucene-queries-6.6.2.jar
org\apache\lucene\lucene-analyzers-phonetic\6.6.2\lucene-analyzers-phonetic-6.6.2.jar
commons-codec\commons-codec\1.11\commons-codec-1.11.jar
org\apache\lucene\lucene-queryparser\6.6.2\lucene-queryparser-6.6.2.jar
io\pivotal\gemfire\geode-wan\9.5.2\geode-wan-9.5.2.jar
antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar
org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.2\aspectjweaver-1.9.2.jar
org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.25\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
org\springframework\geode\spring-geode\1.1.0.RELEASE\spring-geode-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar
org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.1.5.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar
org\springframework\geode\spring-geode-autoconfigure\1.1.0.RELEASE\spring-geode-autoconfigure-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar
javax\cache\cache-api\1.1.0\cache-api-1.1.0.jar
org\springframework\shell\spring-shell\1.2.0.RELEASE\spring-shell-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
com\google\guava\guava\17.0\guava-17.0.jar
jline\jline\2.12\jline-2.12.jar
commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar
com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.8\jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar
com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar
com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.8\jackson-core-2.9.8.jar
org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.6\lombok-1.18.6.jar
org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-test\2.1.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-test-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar
org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-test\2.1.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-test-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar
org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-test-autoconfigure\2.1.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar
com\jayway\jsonpath\json-path\2.4.0\json-path-2.4.0.jar
net\minidev\json-smart\2.3\json-smart-2.3.jar
net\minidev\accessors-smart\1.2\accessors-smart-1.2.jar
org\ow2\asm\asm\5.0.4\asm-5.0.4.jar
junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar
org\assertj\assertj-core\3.11.1\assertj-core-3.11.1.jar
org\mockito\mockito-core\2.23.4\mockito-core-2.23.4.jar
net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.9.10\byte-buddy-1.9.10.jar
net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy-agent\1.9.10\byte-buddy-agent-1.9.10.jar
org\objenesis\objenesis\2.6\objenesis-2.6.jar
org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
org\hamcrest\hamcrest-library\1.3\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar
org\skyscreamer\jsonassert\1.5.0\jsonassert-1.5.0.jar
com\vaadin\external\google\android-json\0.0.20131108.vaadin1\android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar
org\springframework\spring-core\5.1.5.RELEASE\spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar
org\springframework\spring-test\5.1.5.RELEASE\spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar
org\xmlunit\xmlunit-core\2.6.2\xmlunit-core-2.6.2.jar```
````

I've tried using all `Gemfire Starter 1.1.X` versions with `Springboot v2.1.3` and I see similar gemfireCache bean creation issue. 
Can someone let me know if I'm missing anything here and help me with the compatible Gemfire starter to use with `Springboot v.2.1.3` in particular?

Answer (score 2):

@Madmax- To which version compatibility matrix do you refer?  This is the "official" [version compatibility matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/wiki/Spring-Boot-for-Apache-Geode-and-Pivotal-GemFire-Version-Compatibility-Matrix).

As you can see, the latest version of SBDG `1.1.x` is `1.1.6.RELEASE`, which is [based on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.1.6.RELEASE/gradle.properties#L8) Spring Boot `2.1.13.RELEASE`.

If we go back to SBDG `1.1.0.RELEASE` we see that it was [based on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.1.0.RELEASE/gradle.properties#L8) Spring Boot `2.1.7.RELEASE`.  This creates a cascading effect on transitive dependencies.

Since SBDG `1.1.0.RELEASE` is based on Spring Boot `2.1.7.RELEASE`, that means SBDG `1.1.0.RELEASE` also requires Spring Data `Lovelace-SR10` (which is [pulled in](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L169) by Boot `2.1.7.RELEASE`).  Spring Data `Lovelace-SR10` ([here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-build/blob/2.1.10.RELEASE/bom/pom.xml#L7)) [includes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-build/blob/2.1.10.RELEASE/bom/pom.xml#L51-L63) Spring Data for Apache Geode and Pivotal GemFire (SDG) `2.1.10.RELEASE`. Therefore, SBDG `1.1.0.RELEASE` has a minimum requirement of Spring Boot `2.1.7.RELEASE` and SDG `2.1.10.RELEASE`.

If we repeat this exercise for Spring Boot `2.1.3.RELEASE`, we see that Boot [pulls in](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L169) Spring Data Lovelace-SR5 ([here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-build/blob/2.1.5.RELEASE/bom/pom.xml#L7)), which [includes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-build/blob/2.1.5.RELEASE/bom/pom.xml#L51-L63) SDG `2.1.5.RELEASE`.  SDG `2.1.5.RELEASE` does not meet the minimum requirement for SBDG `1.1.0.RELEASE`.

Note, this extends all the way down to the core Spring Framework itself, since Spring Boot is based on and pulls in the core Spring Framework as well, and Spring Data is also based on the core Spring Framework.  Therefore, all the versions must align.

In general, you cannot string together incompatible versions.  If the version compatibility matrix (or more technically, the SBDG `gradle.properties` file, [for example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.1.0.RELEASE/gradle.properties)) states a particular version of a direct or transitive dependency, then that version of the dependency is expected and required.

Having said that, I setup an example/test project with SDDG `1.1.0.RELEASE` based on Spring Boot `2.1.3.RELEASE` to see if I could reproduce your error.  I did!  However, I got a more precise error message:

```java
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.geode.boot.autoconfigure.CacheNameAutoConfiguration$$Lambda$327/0x0000000800e48c40 does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void configure(java.lang.String, org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.ClientCacheFactoryBean)' of interface org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.annotation.ClientCacheConfigurer.
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.ClientCacheFactoryBean.lambda$null$0(ClientCacheFactoryBean.java:118)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.ClientCacheFactoryBean.lambda$new$1(ClientCacheFactoryBean.java:117)
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.ClientCacheFactoryBean.lambda$applyClientCacheConfigurers$2(ClientCacheFactoryBean.java:156)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.ClientCacheFactoryBean.applyClientCacheConfigurers(ClientCacheFactoryBean.java:156)
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.ClientCacheFactoryBean.applyClientCacheConfigurers(ClientCacheFactoryBean.java:142)
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.ClientCacheFactoryBean.applyCacheConfigurers(ClientCacheFactoryBean.java:129)
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.CacheFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CacheFactoryBean.java:177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
    ... 29 more
```

After further investigation, I have traced down the problem.

The SBDG `CacheNameAutoConfiguration` class [uses](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-geode-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/geode/boot/autoconfigure/CacheNameAutoConfiguration.java#L76) the SDG `ClientCacheConfigurer` interface to configure the "name" of the GemFire/Geode cache instance.

The SDG `ClientCacheConfigurer` interface was [defined](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.1.3.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/ClientCacheConfigurer.java#L33-L45) as this in SDG `2.1.5.RELEASE`, which again is pulled in by Spring Boot `2.1.3.RELEASE.  However, in SDG`2.1.10.RELEASE`, I [redefined][13] the`ClientCacheConfigurer`interface (now, an`@FunctionalInterface`as well) in terms of a base`Configurer` interface ([this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.1.10.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/support/Configurer.java)).
While they are the same interface logically, the (method resolution) byte code is no doubt different and therefore, the JRE cannot resolve the method.

You could try excluding the `CacheNameAutoConfiguration` class from your Spring Boot (auto) configuration, like so:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = CacheNameAutoConfiguration.class)
class PccTestApplication { ... }
```

However, SBDG makes liberal use of the `ClientCacheConfigurer` `@FunctionalInterface` in several areas of SBDG's *auto-configuraiton* in order to customize the configuration of SDG, and GemFire/Geode, for conventions and convenience purposes on-behalf of the user.

In fact, I had to exclude both of these SBDG *auto-configuration* classes to get your example/test working correctly.

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { 
    CacheNameAutoConfiguration.class, 
    ContinuousQueryAutoConfiguration.class 
})
class PccTestApplication { ... }
```

For more details on disable auto-configuration, see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.3.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/#geode-configuration-auto-disabling) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.3.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/#geode-auto-configuration-disable).

However, I don't recommend approach as the answer, honestly.

It is pertinent that you use compatible versions, i.e. SBDG `1.1.0.RELEASE` really ought to be paired with the baseline Spring Boot version `2.1.7.RELEASE`.

Even more so, you should strongly consider using SBDG `1.1.6.RELEASE` in the `1.1.x` line with Spring Boot `2.1.13.RELEASE`.

As mentioned in another SO post, SBDG `1.1.7.RELEASE` with Spring Boot `2.1.14.RELEASE` is due this Thursday, 4/30.  See the Spring [release calendar](https://spring-calendar.cfapps.io/) for more information.

I'd also recommend to go even further and upgrade to Spring Boot `2.2.x` (currently, `2.2.6.RELEASE`) with SBDG `1.2.6.RELEASE` if at all possible.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Added my solution here for those who have same issue.

for my case, it was due to version of dependency.
i am using pivotal gemfire 9.10.4 and below 2.2.0 version works well.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-gemfire</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version> <!--it was 2.3.9, and didn't work-->
    </dependency>
```

please refer to the compability matrix for the right version
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/wiki/Spring-Boot-for-Apache-Geode-and-VMware-Tanzu-GemFire-Version-Compatibility-Matrix