# Spring Boot Apache Geode error refused connection: Peer or client version with ordinal 120 not supported

Tags: spring-boot-data-geode

I have the same problem as [geode client server version not supported - Peer or client version with ordinal 100 not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61109190/geode-client-server-version-not-supported-peer-or-client-version-with-ordinal) but another version. My `build.gradle` is

```
// Geode client dependency
implementation 'org.springframework.geode:spring-geode-starter:1.2.4.RELEASE'
// implementation ('org.springframework.data:spring-data-geode:2.2.4.RELEASE')

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.2.4.RELEASE' 

// implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.2.4.RELEASE'  
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:2.4.2'
implementation 'com.lmax:disruptor:3.4.2'

implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-data-geode:2.2.2.RELEASE'
```

It does not seem to matter what version of `spring-geode-starter` is used, the app apparently spins up a Geode 1.13 client

```
Product-Name: Apache Geode
Product-Version: 1.13.1
Source-Date: 2020-11-10 15:51:13 -0800
Source-Repository: support/1.13
Source-Revision: aaa3d13e9c604806624e43ba86d959473226a674
Running on: /192.168.137.1, 8 cpu(s), amd64 Windows 10 10.0 
Communications version: 120
```

The server is using version `1.10` and so the error. Where is the `1.13` client coming from?

There is a log message

```
org.springframework.data.gemfire.support.AbstractFactoryBeanSupport 216 lambda$logInfo$3: Created new Apache Geode version [1.13.1] Cache [MyApi]
```

The `Class path` points to

```
D:\Gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.geode\geode-core\1.13.1\bb09e5da3633d7a16e66b43df7530c36a8c9e91d\geode-core-1.13.1.jar
```

and a lot of other `1.13` geode components

```
org.apache.geode\geode-lucene\1.13.1
org.apache.geode\geode-core\1.13.1
org.apache.geode\geode-cq\1.13.1
org.apache.geode\geode-wan\1.13.1
org.apache.geode\geode-common\1.13.1
org.apache.geode\geode-management\1.13.1
org.apache.geode\geode-gfsh\1.13.1
org.apache.geode\geode-membership\1.13.1
org.apache.geode\geode-tcp-server\1.13.1
org.apache.geode\geode-logging\1.13.1
org.apache.geode\geode-serialization\1.13.1
org.apache.geode\geode-unsafe\1.13.1
```

I checked the [Spring Data Version Compatibility Matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/wiki/Spring-Data-for-Pivotal-GemFire-Version-Compatibility-Matrix) and [Spring Boot for Geode Version Compatibility Matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/wiki/Spring-Boot-for-Apache-Geode-and-Pivotal-GemFire-Version-Compatibility-Matrix) and can't even find a `1.10` server compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

There was a workaround to add `implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-geode:2.2.12.RELEASE'` back into my `build.gradle` got the version to reconcile. Apache Geode `1.9.2` actually refers to Geode `1.10`

There is a possibility to force dependency on Geode 1.10

```
dependencyManagement {
  dependencies {
    dependency 'org.apache.geode:geode-core:1.10.0'
    dependency 'org.apache.geode:geode-cq:1.10.0'
    dependency 'org.apache.geode:geode-lucene:1.10.0'
    dependency 'org.apache.geode:geode-wan:1.10.0'
  }
}
```

but that can lead to [Upgrade to spring-geode-starter 1.4.2 produces condition, introspection and ClassNotFoundExceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66023266/upgrade-to-spring-geode-starter-1-4-2-produces-condition-introspection-and-clas?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The solution is to check the [Version-Compatibility-and-Support-Matrix](http://%20https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/wiki/Spring-Data-for-Apache-Geode-&--Pivotal-GemFire-Version-Compatibility-and-Support-Matrix) and for Geode 1.10 that means using `spring-geode-starter:1.2.8.RELEASE`