# Upgrade to spring-geode-starter 1.4.2 produces condition, introspection and ClassNotFoundExceptions

Tags: spring-data-gemfire, spring-boot-data-geode

On return to a Geode reactive streams project after some time I would like to upgrade to latest spring-geode-starter. Perhaps related to [Spring Boot Geode Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sessionRegion'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66016442/spring-boot-geode-unsatisfied-dependency-expressed-through-method-sessionregion) also on `ClientCacheConfiguration` what I think is a simple `build.gradle` dependencies gives exception:

```
2021-02-03T07:36:55,171 ERROR [main] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication 856 reportFailure: Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.geode.boot.autoconfigure.CachingProviderAutoConfiguration
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:489)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:478)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:478)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:348)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:285)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:569)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300)
    at app.FixApi.main(FixApi.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.annotation.ClientCacheConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2f333739]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:754)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1737)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:753)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:692)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:663)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:238)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:231)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:221)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:169)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/geode/cache/client/SocketFactory
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.geode.cache.client.SocketFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 40 more
```

My `build.gradle` dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
group = 'api'
description = 'streaming api'

// This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
// api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

// Geode client dependency
implementation 'org.springframework.geode:spring-geode-starter:1.4.2'    
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat' 

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:2.4.2'
implementation 'com.lmax:disruptor:3.4.2'

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.4.2'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-rsocket:2.4.2'

// tag::actuator[]
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.4.2'
// end::actuator[]

// HTML manager
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:2.4.2'

implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
implementation 'org.json:json:20201115'

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.1'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.1'

// Geode tests
testImplementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-geode-test:0.0.22'

// Other test dependencies
testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test:3.4.2'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test' 
testImplementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-geode-test:0.0.22'

testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
    exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
}
  
testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.4.2'

// Use JUnit test framework
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure how (reviewing your dependencies in the *Gradle* build shown above), but the `NoClassDefFoundError`/`ClassNotFoundException` on the Apache Geode API class `org.apache.geode.cache.client.SocketFactory` is caused by an incompatible version of Apache Geode (i.e. a version prior to `1.13`).

The [`SocketFactory`](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/client/SocketFactory.html) class was in fact introduced in Apache Geode `1.13` (see [here](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/rel/v1.13.0/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/cache/client/SocketFactory.java), then try [here](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/rel/v1.12.0/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/cache/client/SocketFactory.java)).

Indeed SBDG `1.4.2` [pulls in](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.4.2/gradle.properties#L15) SDG `2.4.3`, which is [based on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/2.4.3/spring-data-geode/pom.xml#L23) Apache Geode `1.13.1`. This is also apparent from the SBDG [Version Compatibility Matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/wiki/Spring-Boot-for-Apache-Geode-and-Pivotal-GemFire-Version-Compatibility-Matrix#version-compatibility-matrix).

You might try running:

```
$ gradlew dependencies | less
```

And searching for all the `org.apache.geode:geode-core` dependencies (simply search for "geode-core") and see which versions of Apache Geode are being used, overridden, etc.

But, anytime you see a `NoClassDefFoundError`/`ClassNotFoundException` or `NoSuchMethodError`, errors of that nature, you can bet that 9 out of 10 times you have a version problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by checking out the [Version-Compatibility-and-Support-Matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/wiki/Spring-Data-for-Apache-Geode-&--Pivotal-GemFire-Version-Compatibility-and-Support-Matrix) and selecting

`implementation 'org.springframework.geode:spring-geode-starter:1.2.8.RELEASE'`